# Issues with conversion between QString and QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, encryption, encoding

I have a strange issue converting QString to QByteArray:

```
qDebug()<<"content to encryp:\n"<<content<<"\n";
QString pwHash = generalSettings.password;
QByteArray secretKey;
secretKey.append(pwHash);
QString clearText(content);

QBlowfish bf(secretKey);
bf.setPaddingEnabled(true);
QByteArray encryptedBa = bf.encrypted(clearText.toUtf8());
           qDebug()<<"encryptedBa:";
           qDebug()<<encryptedBa<<"\n";
const char* cString = encryptedBa.constData();
QString saved = QString::fromUtf8(cString);
QByteArray decryptedBa = bf.decrypted(saved.toUtf8());
           qDebug()<<"decryptedBa:";
           qDebug()<<decryptedBa<<"\n";
```

The output is this:

```
content to encryp:
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta name="qrichtext" content="1" /><style type="text/css">
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
</style></head><body style=" font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;">
<p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">HALLO</p></body></html>" 

encryptedBa: 
"?6N?x9?1!???P?a?+]6H???O??Y?or??l?
??k@???m??d?.?M?o?$F??I(?
7?3??NtE-?fH(?w|sL?i??

cipherText (Input to decrypt): 
"?6N?x9?1!???P?a?+]6H???O??Y?or??l?
??k@???m??d?.?M?o?$F??I(?
7?3??NtE-?fH(?w|sL?i??" 

decryptedBa: 
""
```

Now the strange part: If I switch the line

```
QByteArray decryptedBa = bf.decrypted(saved.toUtf8());
```

to

```
QByteArray decryptedBa = bf.decrypted(encryptedBa);
```

everythink works. BUT: The output is 100% the same, only that the `decryptedBa` at the end is a duplicate of `content`as it should be.
I am also wondering, why the `cipherText` has a " at the end. But that is the same for both versions. What am I missing here?

EDIT:

Following the tip from the answer below and the comments, I came up with this solution:

```
QString saved = encryptedBa.toBase64();
std::string stdString =  std::string(saved.toUtf8().data());
QByteArray fromSaved = QByteArray::fromBase64(stdString.data());
```

The " at the end of the ciphertext is also gone, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cypher text is likely not [valid UTF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8#Description). This means that the data is not guaranteed to properly round-trip through `QString::fromUtf8(data).toUtf8();`.

Double check that `encryptedBa` and `saved.toUtf8()` are actually exactly the same

Comment: how do I check that? What I want to do isn't so much special, so somebody should already know how save and restore...

Comment: QByteArray overloads the `operator!=` so just `if(encryptedBa!=saved.toUtf8)qDebug()<<"cyphertext not valid utf8";`

Comment: Ah, I've been so far. So it is not. Even the `length`is not. And now I don't know what to do.

Comment: @user2366975 don't convert to string, or use base64 if you need text compatible data

Comment: But I need to save this to a text file so it will be a string anyway as far as I see it

Comment: @user2366975 then convert to [base64](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qbytearray.html#toBase64) which is designed to save binary data as text